# Front Flip Animation Bones Rotate After A Certain Degree

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, pose-mode, quaternion

I have this front flip animation that when I rotate it about the X axis as shown in the video linked below, the root and target bones flip all the way back around and then get to the finish pose.

- This animation was originally a quaternion animation but has been since converted to XYZ euler

Video: https://streamable.com/w2wg3a

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Here ya go: https://pasteall.org/blend/b162d4c18ff540259dfaa0c638a0ce18   

It will be the player flip animation.

Comment: could you please describe what you wanted to achieve? You would like the root bone to rotate 360°? for the moment from frame 56 to 64 it goes from 146° to 70° so he's flipping back

Comment: @moonboots Correct.  I am trying to get it to make a full 360° rotation to make it look like a front flip.  (For a double jump)

Comment: So at frame 64 you need to type a number greater than 146°, like 250 or whatever

Comment: @moonboots Ok. I set the root bone to 250 and it seems to have fixed that, but when it goes from 250 to 0 is goes back the other way again.  Also in between 48 and 56 the target bones rotate all the way around for some reason.

Comment: go from 250 to 360

Comment: @moonboots Omg.  Ive had this problem for the past couple of days.  Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment from frame 56 to 64, the root bone goes from 146° to 70°, so your character is flipping back. You need to make the bone rotate from 146 to 250 then 360° for example.

Also, it's better to create a root bone that is completely independent, at the bottom of the character, and not use the spine as the root. Instead parent the spine to the root you've created.